# How does the S3 URL look like when index.html is in a subfolder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a S3 bucket and enabled static web hosting on it.

Then I have uploaded my web assets to `s3://<MY-BUCKET>/sub-folder/my-page`

In the S3 console I can see that I'm given the URL http://MY-BUCKET.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

I thought I could just add `sub-folder/my-page` and the of that URL and it would go to my `index.html` in there however it just returns 404.

That is, I tried the following URL which just returned 404
http://MY-BUCKET.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sub-folder/my-page

So I'm wondering how can I get to that folder?

Comment: Have you configured an index document? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html

Comment: @jellycsc yes, I have, the page works if I put my web assets in the bucket root. The problem I'm facing now is that I cannot put the web assets in a subfolders